# How do I initialize the ArcGIS proxy via server side .NET code (C#)?

Tags: arcgis-server, c#, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, .net, proxy

I know how to do this via JavaScript code:

```
esri.config.defaults.io.proxyUrl = "../proxy.ashx";
```

But, how do I do this in .NET?  I am very new to the GIS space.

Comment: What ArcGIS API are you using?

Comment: @Darksanta
http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/3.5/

Answer (score 1):

Please read the following information.
http://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jshelp/ags_proxy.html

In the "ASP.NET" section, there is the instruction for IIS, and also you can download "proxypage_net.zip" which include proxy.ashx.

Hope this helps you.